# ArrayList with different types of objects

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  SalariedEmployee se = new SalariedEmployee();
  HourlyEmployee he = new HourlyEmployee();
  se.setName("Simos");
  se.setAfm("111440000");
  se.setSalary(4500);
  he.setName("Chatzis");
  he.setAfm("011155555");
  he.setHoursWorked(200);
  he.setHourlyPayment(25);
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  list.add(se);
  list.add(he);
}
```

So I have two objects of different types and I want to add them to a list. How can I make it so that it's safe compiler-wise. Since the objects were created from different classes I cannot use generics when making the list. Or can I change the type of the list after I made it. I mean can I have this

```
ArrayList<SalariedEmployee> list = new ArrayList<SalariedEmployee>();
```

add "se" object of SalariedEmployee and then change the generic to HourlyEmployee and then add the "he" object of HourlyEmployee?

Comment: Tutorials such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html are definitely worth a read in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can create common interface `Employee` and make both classes implement it. So you will be able to use generics:

`List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>()`;

Comment: user does not have Employee class

Comment: @TheGuest so, he have to create it :)

Comment: If you found yourself in the need of having a collection with two types of objects it is very likely that you would want to do something with them later. For all of them. Adding this Employee interface and with a little of good design you would be able to treat both XXXEmployee and YYYEMployee polymorphically

Comment: This is a case for an abstract class not an interface.

Comment: @Rarw but rule of the thumb yes, but could be not. It will work eitherway and it is up to ohyez96 to decide which is better for his model.

Comment: I thought of this but the problem is that the above is part of an excercise so I am not allowed to change certain things in classes. for example employee must be an abstract class I cannot change it to an interface even though they are somewhat the "same".

Comment: @ohyez96 there's no reason to change it to an interface. Using an abstract class here makes logical sense from a design perspective. HourlyEmployee and SalariedEmployee are both concrete implementations of a broader abstract concept - someone who is an employee. Just make your concrete classes extend the employee class and you should be fine.

Comment: I have done that but still get compiler warning if I use <Employee> generic

Comment: my bad I have accidentally put <Employee> like this
ArrayList<Employee> list = new <Employee>ArrayList();
instead of this
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
which i thought was the same but itsnt since i dont get compiler warning anymore

Comment: @ohyez96 right, the type comes after ArrayList<T> a cast comes before (Employee) e;

Answer (score 2):

Creating the interface:

Employee.java

```
public interface Employee {
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getName();

    public void setAfm(String afm);
    public String getAfm();

}
```

Then create the two classes implementing it, adding their unique methods:

HourlyEmployee.java

```
public class HourlyEmployee implements Employee {

    private String name;
    private String afm;
    private int hoursWorked;
    private int hourlyPayment;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAfm(String afm) {
        this.afm = afm;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAfm() {
        return this.afm;
    }

    public int getHoursWorked() {
        return this.hoursWorked;
    }

    public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    public int getHourlyPayment() {
        return this.hourlyPayment;
    }

    public void setHourlyPayment(int hourlyPayment) {
        this.hourlyPayment = hourlyPayment;
    }
}
```

SalariedEmployee.java

```
public class SalariedEmployee implements Employee {

    private String name;
    private String afm;
    private int salary;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAfm(String afm) {
        this.afm = afm;

    }

    @Override
    public String getAfm() {
        return this.afm;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Then to test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
         SalariedEmployee se = new SalariedEmployee();
          HourlyEmployee he = new HourlyEmployee();
          se.setName("Simos");
          se.setAfm("111440000");
          se.setSalary(4500);
          he.setName("Chatzis");
          he.setAfm("011155555");
          he.setHoursWorked(200);
          he.setHourlyPayment(25);
          ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
          list.add(se);
          list.add(he);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an Employee class that these two can inherit from and use that in the ArrayList

```
public abstract class Employee 
{
    public string setName(string name) { ... }
    public string setAfm(string afm) { ... }
    public int setSalary(float afm) { ... }
}

public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee
{
}

public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
}

ArrayList<Employee> employees;
```

This will also mean you will not have to rewrite your setter methods for each employee class

Comment: Why is all the classes are abstract?

Comment: 1) Using `interface` is better then `abstract class`; 2) it is better to declare type of variable using interface, i.e. not `ArrayList<...> employess` but `List<...>`

Comment: @Andremoniy Can you explain why please? I thought that abstract class would be a better fit but I am willing to learn otherwise

Comment: Coding to Interfaces is good practice indeed. having said that, Interfaces are useful in scenarios while bringing some value addition to unrelated entity, e.g. Clonable. In scenarios like above, where enities are related and part of a family (Employee, salaried employee etc) - abstract class is way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a superclass "employee" and make both objects children of employee:

```
class Employee { }
class SalariedEmployee extends Employee { }
class HourlyEmployee extends Employee { }

Employee salariedEmp = new SalariedEmployee();
Employee hourlyEmp = new HourlyEmployee();
```

Then create an array list of type Employee:

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new <Employee>ArrayList();
```

Comment: tried this but now I have compiler warning for the methods I use because the objects are of type Employee which is a superclass and doesnt contain the methods I use.

Comment: you can add the method to the superclass instead of the subclasses, and only override it if needed in the subclasses

Answer (score -3):

The initialization like below to add to list.

```
> List<Object> list = new <Object>ArrayList();
```

To read from the list later, you could use `instanceof` and cast to the known type that you have in your code.

Comment: Please explain reason for downvote. Please do not just "downvote".

Comment: Down vote because there's a better solution to this problem than simply using object and then an instance of check each time. What if there were 100 employee subtypes? You'd really instanceof every instance?

Comment: good point but the OP doesn't have 100 subtypes. The better way would be to consult the OP for their requirement. Not a good idea to just assume on "how" the OP should do something but it is alway a good idea to find out "what" is needed!